# Find all positive integers $a$ and $n$ such that $\sqrt{n-a}+\sqrt{(n-a)+1}+\dots+\sqrt{n}+\dots+\sqrt{(n+a)-1}+\sqrt{n+a}$ is rational.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

Find all positive integers $a$ and $n$ such that $$\sqrt{n-a}+\sqrt{(n-a)+1}+\dots+\sqrt{n}+\dots+\sqrt{(n+a)-1}+\sqrt{n+a}$$
is rational.
Attempt to problem: I tried considering $a$ as a constant and from that to find $n$, but it got nowhere.

Comment: Maybe try to check what's happening for low $a$. For example, if $a=0$ then we've got $\sqrt{n}$ which is rational if and only if $n=k^2$ for some integer $k$

Comment: I tried for a=1. I sqared it. But vain

Comment: Maybe try to use some properties of polynomials.

Comment: I don't think the $a$ is important so much as what are possible odd length of consectutive roots of integers.

Answer (score 2):

Let us assume that $n>a$, so none of the expressions under the squares is $0$. If this is not the case, the proof below can easily be adapted to cover such situation.

If you write $n-k= q_k^2\cdot m_k$, where $m_k$ is square-free, for $-a\leqslant k\leqslant a$, the above expression $E$ is equal to $\sum_{k=-a}^aq_k\sqrt{m_k}$. Of course, some $m_k$'s are maybe equal to $1$, but all $q_k$'s are positive. Let $u_1,\ldots,u_l$ be all different numbers among $m_k$'s. So $E$ is actually equal to $\sum_{i=1}^l\alpha_i\sqrt{u_i}$, where $\alpha_i$ is the sum of those $q_k$'s for which $m_k=u_i$. In particular, all $\alpha_i$'s are strictly positive. Note one more thing, since $a\geqslant 1$, we must have some $m_k\neq 1$, i.e. $l\geqslant 2$. Now we see that it is not possible that $E\in\mathbb Q$, because $\sqrt{u_i}$'s are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$, because $u_i$'s are pairwise different square-free numbers, and in $E=\sum_{i=1}^l\alpha_i\sqrt{u_i}$ at least one member doesn't vanish.

Thus such positive $n$ and $a$ don't exist.

Comment: You have a typo ($n-k = q_k^2 \cdot m_k$). Is it a known result that the set $\lbrace 1, \sqrt{u_1},..., \sqrt{u_l} \rbrace $ is linearly Independent if the $u_i$ are square-free?

Comment: @PaulFrost Thanks for the correction! There is a known fact that $F=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{p_1},\ldots,\sqrt{p_n})$ , where $p_i$'s are different primes, is an extension of $\mathbb Q$ of degree $2^n$. This means that the basis for $F$ over $\mathbb Q$ is exactly $\{\sqrt{p_1}^{e_1}\ldots\sqrt{p_n}^{e_n}\mid (\forall i)e_i\in\{0,1\}\}$. (Here I use more theory about field extensions.) Now from this we can conclude the linear independence above.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! (+1)